# Google Analytic not reporting analytics for food bloggers.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, google-analytics

We have a food recipe blog site where bloggers post there recipes on our website and link in our website will take users to their website when they click read more button for recipe. It has been all working fine with our old website where the new link opened in the same window. But we launched our new website and made it so that more information links would open from a new window with target _blank. but the problem now is, in bloggers analytic accounts it doesn't reflect as traffic coming from our website but instead it is showing as direct traffic. Is there any way to get this fixed so still it will open from a new tab with target blank and it will report traffic to bloggers analytic as traffic from our website instead direct traffic.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I hope [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/analytics/asynchronous-tracking-code-snippet/lq43Ra6HxaA) will solve your problem